# create an angularjs directive to wrap jquery tagcanvas plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to implement an animated word cloud. Since I did not found any angular or Ionic ready plugins to do what i wanted, I decided (and I found it interesting to learn) to create an angular wrapper for a jquery code.
The plugin is [tagcanvas](http://www.goat1000.com/jquery.tagcanvas.js?2.9), and the usage example is [this](http://codepen.io/deadbead/pen/FrKvi)

What I have done so far:

- I added the jquery js file to my index.html
- I created a js file where I declared my directive, and added it to index.html:

**tagcanvas.js**

```
angular.module('tagCanvas', [])

.directive('tagCanvas', function() {

return {

  restrict: 'E',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {


        element.tagcanvas({


            outlineColour: attrs.outlineColour,
            reverse: attrs.reverse,
            depth: attrs.depth,
            maxSpeed: attrs.maxSpeed,
            textFont: attrs.textFont,
            textColour: attrs.textColour,
            weightMode: attrs.weightMode,
            weight: attrs.weight
        }, attrs.canvas);



  }
};

});
```

As you can see in the codepen example, there are attributes that I need to call, and a html element id `canvas`, which I did not know how to call them in my directive.

My second problem is that I don't know how to create and call the words that I want to display in my tag cloud.
I looked over lots of tutorials, but I still don't know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would not name your Angular app and directive with the same name. Not only is it confusing, but it may not work properly. Second, although there may be many ways to approach this, here is how I would do it:

**directive**
(I have changed the directive to an attribute rather than an element and used an isolate scope for the attributes. The link function is wrapped in a `$timeout` to ensure the element exists in the DOM prior to trying to call `tagcanvas`.)

```
.directive("tagCanvas", function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            canvasId: "@",
            outlineColour: "@",
            reverse: "@",
            depth: "@",
            maxSpeed: "@",
            textFont: "@",
            textColour: "@",
            weightMode: "@",
            weight: "@"
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $timeout(function() {
                element.tagcanvas({
                    outlineColour: scope.outlineColour,
                    reverse: scope.reverse,
                    depth: scope.depth,
                    maxSpeed: scope.maxSpeed,
                    textFont: scope.textFont,
                    weightMode: scope.weightMode,
                    weight: scope.weight
                }, scope.canvasId);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

**controller**
(You would likely want to get your word list from a service or some other storage, but for illustration I have hardcoded an array in the controller)

```
.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.wordList = [
        {
            href: "#",
            fontSize: "2.83ex",
            text: "1000"
        }, {
            href: "#",
            fontSize: "4.8ex",
            text: "example"
        }, {
            href: "#",
            fontSize: "8.77ex",
            text: "gif"
        }, {
            href: "#",
            fontSize: "2.83ex",
            text: "svg"
        }, {
            href: "#",
            fontSize: "8.77ex",
            text: "jpg"
        }, {
            href: "#",
            fontSize: "10.68ex",
            text: "png"
        }, {
            href: "#",
            fontSize: "2.83ex",
            text: "bmp"
        }, {
            href: "#",
            fontSize: "4.8ex",
            text: "img"
        }
    ];
})
```

**html**

```
<div>
    <canvas width="300"
            height="300"
            id="myCanvas"
            tag-canvas
            canvas-id="tags"
            outline-colour="#ff00ff"
            text-font="Arial"
            text-colour="#ff00ff"
            reverse="true"
            depth="0.8"
            max-speed="0.05"
            weight-mode="both" 
            weight="true"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="tags" style="font-size: 50%;">
    <a ng-repeat="word in wordList" href="{{word.href}}" style="font-size: {{word.fontSize}}">{{word.text}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have an error saying 'tagcanvas' function is not a function, though I made sure to add the jquery.tagcanvas.js and tagcanvas.js :/

Comment: You must have referenced something incorrectly. Here is a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4DR5FjttC2CP0KkDcwaW?p=preview) with the exact code from my answer.

Comment: I have an issue with the controller. I did not understand where to declare it. Because I have a module called starter.Clients with a controller called clientsController, and it is where I want to use the tagCloud (clients.html). So do I need to call 'ctrl' controller than you created in clientsController? :/ Im pretty confused.

Comment: I don't understand your question. As a matter of expediency I used `app` and `ctrl` in the demo I provided. Other than storing the word list, the controller is sort of irrelevant to your question so you shouldn't have to change anything in your code. I simply showed how you can wrap tagcanvas in a directive - how you get the list of words, their respective sizes and hrefs and then output them into a div that tagcanvas can use is sort of ancillary to the question and will likely be very specific to your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an example plunker with a working example where you can dynamically add new tags:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zR4pxcZlqPxr8pnhsNRI?p=preview

It is not that easy to use tagcanvas inside of an AngularJS directive. Tagcanvas relies heavily on a certain DOM representation. This can sometimes be at odds with the way AngularJS works. Because of that I had to use the `$timeout` service for example.

It would be better to make a "component" out of you tagcanvas directive which itself is responsible for its HTML.

```
app.directive('tagCanvas', function($timeout) {

  return {
    scope: {
      tagData: '='
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: '<canvas width=300 height=300" id="my-canvas"></canvas>' +
    '<div id="tags"><a ng-repeat="tag in tagData" ng-bind="tag.name"></a></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find('canvas').tagcanvas({
          outlineColour: '#ff00ff',
          reverse: true,
          depth: 0.8,
          maxSpeed: 0.05,
          textFont: null,
          textColour: null,
          weightMode: 'both',
          weight: true
        }, 'tags');

        scope.$watch('tagData', function(newValue) {
          $timeout(function() {
            element.find('canvas').tagcanvas('reload');
          }, 0);
        }, true);
    }
  };

});
```